# How to do a live update to an HTML form using javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to live update a text field in html using javascript, that is as the user is typing text in one field, the contents are being displayed in another as they type. i need just a short code snippet to do that. eg as a person is typing their name, the name is being typed one letter at a time at another position on the screen.

Answer (score 3):

Give the two fields an `id` each, then use something like this:

```
document.getElementById("field1").onkeyup = function() {
   document.getElementById("field2").value = this.value;   
}
```

All it does is bind an event listener to the `onkeyup` event, which fires every time a key is released. In the event listener, it simply copies the value of the field which received the event to another field, specified by `id`.

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/2crfB/).

Comment: @ThinkingStiff - Thanks, not sure how that happened! I've fixed it now.